# p/Contents/MacOS/Electron Helper[5250]: ../../third_party/electron_node/src/inspector_agent.cc:746:bool node::inspector::Agent::Star

Tags: electron

when I am tring to debug electron5.0.6, the console panel echo the following errors:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:2004/devtools/browser/af404ae0-e43f-4783-8b18-2662f58a7a42
/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron Helper[5250]: 
../../third_party/electron_node/src/inspector_agent.cc:
746:bool node::inspector::Agent::StartIoThread():
  Assertion `(client_) != nullptr' failed.
```

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:2004/devtools/browser/af404ae0-e43f-4783-8b18-2662f58a7a42
/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron Helper[5250]: ../../third_party/electron_node/src/inspector_agent.cc:746:bool node::inspector::Agent::StartIoThread(): Assertion `(client_) != nullptr' failed.
 1: 0x111559ac5 node::Abort() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 2: 0x1115592bf node::Assert(node::AssertionInfo const&) [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 3: 0x111600685 node::inspector::Agent::StartIoThread() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 4: 0x111608533 node::inspector::Agent::GetWorkerManager() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 5: 0x10d43a66f v8::internal::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, v8::internal::BasicBlockProfiler const&) [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 6: 0x10d3f8ace v8::internal::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, v8::internal::BasicBlockProfiler const&) [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 7: 0x10d3f7f4a v8::internal::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, v8::internal::BasicBlockProfiler const&) [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 8: 0x10dcbcc4b v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 9: 0x10dc1ccf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
10: 0x10dc1ccf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
11: 0x10dc16500 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
12: 0x10dc1ccf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
13: 0x10dc1ccf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
14: 0x10dc1ccf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
15: 0x10dc1ccf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron Helper[5251]: ../../third_party/electron_node/src/inspector_agent.cc:746:bool node::inspector::Agent::StartIoThread(): Assertion `(client_) != nullptr' failed.
 1: 0x10767fac5 node::Abort() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 2: 0x10767f2bf node::Assert(node::AssertionInfo const&) [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 3: 0x107726685 node::inspector::Agent::StartIoThread() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 4: 0x10772e533 node::inspector::Agent::GetWorkerManager() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 5: 0x10356066f v8::internal::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, v8::internal::BasicBlockProfiler const&) [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 6: 0x10351eace v8::internal::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, v8::internal::BasicBlockProfiler const&) [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 7: 0x10351df4a v8::internal::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, v8::internal::BasicBlockProfiler const&) [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 8: 0x103de2c4b v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
 9: 0x103d42cf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
10: 0x103d42cf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
11: 0x103d3c500 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
12: 0x103d42cf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
13: 0x103d42cf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
14: 0x103d42cf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
15: 0x103d42cf7 v8::internal::trap_handler::RemoveTrapHandler() [/Users/deo/WebstormProjects/workPlace/ElectronStudy2/electron-quick-start/node_modules/_electron@5.0.6@electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework]
```

Comment: What is the code that produces this error?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this error?